# add css to print or echo

Tags: php, css

How can you apply css to a specific element inside your php?

example:

```
print "<p> whatever </p>
```

Will it work or be correct to:

```
print <p> id assigned "what") whatever </p>
```

and then inside the css; add the style to that id?

Further:

Can you do this to something like an input type and round the corners with a border-radius?

Comment: use the ticks '`' for code block. And you are on the right track. Basically just assign class / id and let css do the rest

Comment: Use the `{}` tool in the input editor to mark code blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would do something like

```
print('<p id="what"> whatever </p>');
```

or

```
echo '<p id="what"> whatever </p>';
```

Comment: So I can assign an id to a paragraph inside my <?php ?> block just the same as you would in html; then manipulate that inside my css?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
print "<p class='whatever'>some data</p>";
```

and then put the style for `.whatever` in your CSS file or a `<style>` block in the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

When you print via PHP, it will print it exactly as if you wrote it in HTML. There's three ways you can do it.

1) Add a class

```
print "<p class="what"> whatever </p>
```

2) Set an id

```
print "<p id="what"> whatever </p>
```

3) Style it directly

```
print "<p style="width:50px;"> whatever </p>
```